# The impact of native code in Android/iPhone app development

Tags: android, iphone, c++, ios, native-code

I want to create an app for Android **and** for iOS.

Now, I have to use lot of native C++ code in my application.
So I'd like to know:

- Are any performance issues regarding the use of native code?
- Is it possible to have full control over resources (of the mobile phone) using native code?
- Are there any limitations or drawbacks in using native code in Android or iOS?
- Can you recommend high usage of native code in Android/iOS app development? or perhaps it is discouraged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full access to the native UI controls and events will usually involve using Objective C on iOS and Java for Dalvik on Android.  The compute kernel, Model object internals, Open GL rendering, and such, can all be done in C/C++.  On Mac OS X and iOS, Objective C++ **is** native code, and thus will run as fast as native code (assuming your code itself isn't slow).  On Android, there may be a small overhead calling through the NDK interface.

The iOS security sandbox does not allow full access to the control of all resources from any app on a stock OS device.

Comment: Does the c++ as native code works Properly on other platform(Windows,Linux,Mac,Symbian) ?

Answer (score 3):

I don't have any IOS dev. experience so I'm just gonna talk about Android.

[Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html) is used for using the native code.

NDK promises several, not full, control of the resources. It's not suggested to implement your app purely using native code. "In general, you should only use native code if it is essential to your application, not just because you prefer to program in C/C++." Details in #When to Develop in Native Code.

Comment: I do not want to use lot of native code as i prefer to program in C/C++ but my application is already built in c++ and its huge so i want if most of (not necessary all) code can be just reused.

Comment: Reasonable enough. But as native code, the complicity of the whole app would be raised. And even though, you'll have to rewrite the codes any way to suit the JNI, and it would be hard to debug.

Answer (score 1):

you can use **c** or **c++** code as well as **objective-c** on iOS (in case of **c++** you need to rename source file from *.m to *.mm). but apple do not recommed it. Do not shure about android.

### **EDIT**

Also, I just remembered: my friend used thirdprty library in **c** in android. So, you can use it there too

Comment: I heard that `apple do not recommend` but whats the issue ? is there any detailed information?

Comment: this just wrote in there docs and I didn't see any detailed information. But once i used thirdparty library written in c/c++ and worked fine. Dont have any idea what can be wrong here. Also, I just remembered: my friend used thirdprty library in **c** in android. So, you can use it there too

Comment: AFAIK Apple does not recommend to use Obj-C++ as your global base language i.e. mixing Obj-C with C++ all over the application because it will mess up your project. When I wrote my library and integrate it in the app, I used .cpp for lib code and .c as interface - this worked fine.

Comment: Objective C++ is fine as a base language. I have used it commercially in my mapping and navigation product for many years. It works perfectly and gives me full access to all of modern C++. My code consists of a core library in pure C++, plus an Objective C interface providing a wrapper over the core library; the wrapper uses Objective C classes and methods, but its internal implementation is in Objective C++ . That gives my clients a complete API for both Objective C and Swift.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS: It's totally fine to use Objective-C++ — my game code was in C++ and so most of the UI (that talks to C++ model objects) is in Objective-C++. C++ is just as native as Objective-C, both can be considered C dialects that compile to machine instructions.